# Derivative of an interpolated function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, interpolation

I am trying to take the derivative of an interpolated function. I am given the function values and the derivatives at some irregular points. Here is my minimal working example to reproduce the error:

```
i = Interpolation[Table[{{2 t}, Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 4, 0.01}]]
Plot[i[t], {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image: The plot looks fine]

```
Plot[i'[t], {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image: while the derivative is not ok]

Apparently the interpolation is working, but not the derivative. Is there something I am doing wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember the chain rule. You feed `Interpolation` with very contradictory information: The first derivative does not fit the parameterization of the curve.

This works better:

```
i = Interpolation[Table[{{2 t}, Sin[t], 1/2 Cos[t]}, {t, 0., 4., 0.01}]];
GraphicsRow[{
  Plot[i[t], {t, 0, 4}],
  Plot[i'[t], {t, 0, 4}]
  }]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you may use

```
i = Interpolation[Table[{{t}, Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0., 4., 0.01}]];
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Of course you're right. I removed it.

Answer (score 5):

There is no error.

Given

```
f = Interpolation[Table[{{2 t}, Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 4, 0.01}]]
```

when you make the plot

```
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 8}]
```

[image: plot_1]

it looks like a nice smooth curve which should have a smooth derivative, but if you plot a small section of the domain, like this

```
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, .1}]
```

[image: plot_2]

you see it is actually highly oscillatory, which explains your derivative plot.